# My link doesn't have the effects that i put in

Tags: javascript, html, css

The links that i made remain in the default colour scheme

```
nav ul li a{
    color: #white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li a::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: #d6799e;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -6px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
nav ul li a:hover:after:{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I tried to not get the default link colours

Comment: Please also add the html code. An error i can see is that you're using `color: #white;` which is invalid. You use # for hex color codes, for keywords like white the syntax is simply: `color: white;`, if you use the Developer Console it will highlight these invalid properties automatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the # on the CSS like that:

```
nav ul li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
}
```

You need to put # only if it's a HEX color like #FFFFFF or #000000. Listen more about HEX color [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hex-color).

Have a good day!